# I have a 32 bit application which has a need for a dependency on a 64 bit dll

Tags: x86-64, dll-injection

I have a rather large application built in visual studio which runs in x86 and have recently had a need to integrate a library which is only built in x64.  Is there a way to utilize an x64 dependency in x86 mode or do I need to build a seperate application, somehow call it then maybe pass the data back to the parent application via a socket or something????  Any Suggestions?

Comment: You need to build a separate application. You can't mix 32 and 64 bit executables. Maybe its time to port the 32bit application to x64.

Comment: thx. yeah we can't go 64, it creates crazy memory issues.

Comment: Communicating via a socket works. You could use shared memory though.

Comment: Another option I am trying to pursue is actually executing an external application and grabbing the ErrorLevel for the results I need... However it keeps crashing out. I think it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a second application to run in 64 and set up listeners for console output and error output in order to pass data back